# How to setup LogBack Configuration

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I'm completely new to LogBack, and I'd like to use it. I notice that you can use a Configuration as an XML, but I have no idea how to implement that XML and have Logback use that instead of the default one.

My programs packages are like `me.iarekylew00t.a.b` and so on. It'll also be compiled into a runnable JAR at the end. How should I go about adding a `logback.xml` file, without the enduser needing to have it?

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I've been trying to look this up for hours and I can't find anything that clearly tells someone how to go about adding a configuration - most assume you already know how... Thanks. (please be as detailed as possible)

Comment: Have you gone through the logback manual? It is very comprehensive.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes, I've tried going through that and I couldn't seem to get it working. I'm not sure if I'm just missing something or what, but I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: @RC - But wouldn't the logback.xml need to be added to the classpath when I compile the project into a jar?

Comment: Yes it needs to be at the same level as your topmost class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `logback.xml` in the root of your classpath containing (tune to your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </encoder>
     </appender>

     <logger name="some.logger.name" level="INFO"/>

     <root level="DEBUG">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </root>
</configuration>
```

and that's all.

EDIT: usual directory structure:

```
src/main/java/
    some/package/
                 someClass.java
    some/other/package/
                 someOtherClass.java
src/main/resources/
    logback.xml
```

in the jar:

```
some/package/
          someClass.class
some/other/package/
          someOtherClass.class
logback.xml
```

Comment: When doing this, after I export the project to a runnable JAR, it throws a NullPointerException. I've gotten it working in the project though.

Comment: That's another problem, edit your question and add a full stacktrace of the NullPointerException

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. It was something else throwing an error. I added logback.xml much like the way you have it setup above and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by copying logback.xml to src/main/java - this was the only way I found to make the executable JAR find it and use it.

Since I didn't want to have two (possibly different) config files, I kept the original logback.xml in my src/resources folder (where Eclipse would find it and use it during development) and replaced the one under src/main/java with a symlink. Works well for me.